# angular Cannot read property 'toString' of null in httprequest

Tags: angularjs

I'm making an http get request this way:

```
this.http.get('http://www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?*[amenity=hospital][bbox=13.20524,43.70861,13.22842,43.72338]')
.subscribe(
data => {
    console.log(data.toString());
 });
```

but the following error is given:

```
Cannot read property 'toString' of null
```

I've also tried mapping the result this way:

```
this.http.get('http://www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?*[amenity=hospital][bbox=13.20524,43.70861,13.22842,43.72338]')
.map(res => res.toString())
.subscribe(
data => {
    console.log(data);
 });
```

but the error remains. Why is it saying that it's null, since I use the method inside subscribe function?
Also, if I go to `http://www.overpass-api.de/api/xapi?*[amenity=hospital][bbox=13.20524,43.70861,13.22842,43.72338]` the xml file I get is not null.

Comment: the response is an xml ?

Comment: toString() doesn't work on an xml document.  Not sure what your trying to do with the xml document but you probably need to implement some form of parser and/or serializer in order to read the data in the document

Comment: The response is actually a xapi file, but I thought it could be read as xml file since it starts with xml tags. Right now I don't know, is there a way to convert xapi to xml?